# How to tune the Red Bull X2010 to make easier to drive?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I'm trying to do the Special Seasonal Event with the Red Bull X2010, that GT5 send for the win of Sebastian Vettel.

I've found that this car is very hard to drive for me, and after several laps, all the times are worse than the third time, and also are invalid (because I went out of the track).

What can I do to make this car easier to drive?

(Apart of practice a lot, of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you increase the downforce front and rear this should make the car a lot more stable.

Adjusting the limited-slip differential can also make a significant difference to the car's handling. I found increasing the settings helped a lot, particularly accelerating out of low-speed corners.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the simulation (TCS, ASM, skid recovery, controller sensitivity etc). You could set the power limiter to get a less peaky engine response and lower max power. Use the stickiest tires you can. The usual.

But there probably isn't any magic to be done. The fantasy X car already handles incredibly well. It's just insanely fast. You need to learn how it handles, what speed you can take through different corners, what kind of line lets you keep the sped (and df) high in this car etc. Never go off the track :)

Like with the Escudo, you can always shortshift massively to avoid being at top revs when you're not doing maximum straight-line acceleration. There's still a huge amount of power at lower rev range, but it'll be a little more tame and you won't have to time the shifts very carefully.

You might be able to save a B-spec lap and yours on the same track and compare your driving to Bob's. See if there's some spots where you lose a lot of time. Eventually the trick will be inhuman precision and zen driving rhythm.

Doing an endurance event with it will get you practice :)